# Scheduling a dependency graph for parallel computing

Tags: algorithms, graphs, parallel-computing

**Background:**

I have a dependency graph, i.e. a directed graph where the nodes are tasks and the edges are dependency relations. Moreover, nodes are assigned a weight since they take different amount of time to complete.

I have developed an algorithm that rearranges the graph by merging some nodes together that can be computed as one task instead of several separate tasks (this is not parallel computing), i.e. the algorithm reduces the number of tasks. However, this algorithm doesn't always give one rearrangement of the graph but can produce many, e.g. three graphs where all of them are in some sense the same graph but rearranged.

**What I want to do is the following:**

I want to determine which one of the different rearranged graphs is the "best" where "best" is determined by some type of grading criteria. I was thinking this criteria could be some type of measurement of parallel degree that takes the weights in consideration. I have tried just using a topological sort but I find this approach a bit to primitive. After picking a graph, I would also want to produce a scheduling list of the tasks. The weights can be seen as estimations on how long a given task will take to complete, but these are only rough estimations.

**Questions:**

What kind of measurement of parallel degree could I use and what algorithms are there for grading this and also for scheduling the tasks accordingly?

Comment: Time to completion?

Comment: Is [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2524/getting-parallel-items-in-dependency-resolution/2525#2525) what you want to do?

Comment: Yes that could definitely be a way to perform the actual  parallel computations. However, I also want to select the reordered graph which is best suited for that parallelization. If I have two graphs g1 and g2, I want to  select the graph that will give me the least time to completion but obviously I want to do this without actually calculating both g1 and g2.

Comment: Also, do you know of any litterature I can read some more in the kind of parallelization you mentioned? Preferably the more practical oriented if you would know any.

Comment: "obviously I want to do this without actually calculating both g1 and g2" -- I see. You'll have to specify precisely what inputs you have and what kind of restructurings you allow, then. Otherwise, we can not come up with a tailored routine for minimizing the longest path.

Comment: No, I don't know any resources. I came up with that formulation on the spot; it's not terribly sophisticated, after all. The basic principle is, "process everything you can at every point in time". It's still optimal, though, because you can not finish faster than the longest path.

Comment: How would your routine look like in Python code for a random DAG? I'm having trouble implementing it.

Comment: We don't do programming questions here. That said, the pseudocode I give in [my answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2525/98) should be straight-forward to implement using parallel or concurrency features of your programming language of choice.